# How to navigate to a MAUI shell?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui

My app has the following flow,

1. Login Page (ContentPage)
2. Home Page (Shell with tabs)
3. Delivery Page (Shell with tabs)

The idea is that a user is presented with a login page and once logged in, I want the app to go to the shell and then from the shell, I can go to the Delivery page which is also a shell.

The reason I want to use a shell is because I wanted to have a tabbed view. I like the way the Shell + tabs look compared to the TabbedPage.

When I tried to set the App's Main Page at runtime, the app crashes.

My goal is to have 2 different set of tab bars one for home page and another one for delivery. Let's say the login page is just a plain page with no tabs, the home page has three tabs (example: Accounts, Settings, Dashboard) and the Delivery Page has its own tabs (example: Customer, Map, Payment).

What is the proper way to implement this scenario?

Comment: how about [reading the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation?view=net-maui-8.0) ?

Comment: @FabriBertani, I've been to the documentation. What we can get from that is basic navigation but doesn't mention anything about having two shells or multiple tabbed pages.

Comment: You may create a new AppShell and try ```Application.Current.MainPage = new AppShell2();```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the default MAUI project the shell *is* the app main page and in many scenarios can simply stay that way. `Login`, `Home` and `Delivery` are essentially the Shell.Content that gets switched in and out of the shell in the process of navigating. If you set `Shell.TabBarIsVisible="False"` for the `Login`  page and show that first, the user should be forced to enter credentials before the other pages (that have the shared tab bar) can be navigated to.

[image: login page]

###### Shell

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="dynamic_tabbed_view.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:dynamic_tabbed_view"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled"
    Shell.TabBarIsVisible="False">

    <TabBar>
        <Tab Title="Logout" >
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoginPage}" />
        </Tab>
        <Tab Title="Home" Route="home">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:HomePage}" />
        </Tab>
        <Tab Title="Delivery" Route="delivery">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:DeliveryPage}" />
        </Tab>
    </TabBar>
</Shell>
```

###### Login

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="dynamic_tabbed_view.LoginPage"
    Title="Login"
    Shell.TabBarIsVisible="False">
    <Grid>
        <Button 
            Text="Login"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            Clicked="Login_Clicked"/>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

---

###### Home and Delivery shared TabBar

*For example:*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="dynamic_tabbed_view.HomePage"
    Title="Home"
    Shell.TabBarIsVisible="True">
    <Grid>
        <Label 
            Text="Welcome to .NET MAUI!"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

[image: home and delivery with shared tab bar]

Comment: What I'm aiming for is to have two different set of tab bars for the home and the delivery.

Comment: Let me ask you if they really need to be different tab bars, or maybe you just want to show different options depending on the selected page? To me, the easy thing to do would be binding the "IsVisible" properties of the various `Tab` objects. So different pages can have different tabs but you're keeping with the "single shell" paradigm. Just a thought...

Comment: that makes sense. I think that works. The reason I posted this is that I want to get input on how could that be properly implemented. That approach may not be the most ideal way to do it, by setting visibility. But That would work. Thanks!